# replace number only from a string

Tags: javascript, replace

i have a problem in replace '.' from a particular variable, 
   var a = "test.test 2.5 test", 
   my expected result is "test.test 25 test" so i want remove '.' from number(2.5 to 25) but not from any letters(test.test must remain test.test). Is any way to do this in JavaScript?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Even better:

```
"test.test 2.5 test".replace(/(\d)\.(\d)/, "$1$2");
```

This works:

```
"test.test 2.5 test".replace(/(\d)\.(\d)/, function(a, b, c) { return b + c; });
```

This replaces `<digit> <dot> <digit>` with `<digit> <digit>`.

Comment: "test.test 2.5 test".replace(/(\d)\.(\d)/, "$1$2") is another solution.